# Is the "Greenhouse Boy" the same person as the main antagonist in the TV anime version of Wish upon the Pleiades?

Tags: wish-upon-the-pleiades

[In the ONA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish_Upon_the_Pleiades#Episode_list), they were the same person.

But in TV anime version, Subaru does not seem to recognize him (or at least she is keeping her cards hidden from the other girls).

Their appearance are somehow similar (the horns could be a part of the outfit), but the personality of the horned guy who attempts to steal the fragments, and the greenhouse kid are radically different.

Are they the same person in the TV anime as well?

Comment: They are the same person. What do you expect?

Comment: Dunno. Evil twin, evil clone, mirror universe, there are so many possibilities. Gainax is renowed for twisting their stories beyond recognition on each retelling, for once.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much from this series, though. Gainax has gone down hill since Gurren Lagann.